# Unable to POST on Apache 2.2.17 (Unix)

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I am having an issue with an apache installation where any POST request is causing:

```
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

Or

```
Error 115 Connection Reset
```

I setup a basic test below and apache fails everytime. Anyone have an idea about what could be causing this? Thanks!

```
 <?php
     // Note: This is running on my localhost:8080
    if(isset($_POST)) print_r($_POST);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="posttest.php">
        <input type="text" name="test" value="test" />
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: what version of *nix? how did you install Apache?

Comment: @Dagon Linux x86 2.6.36.1  - Angstrom GNU/Linux v2012

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem.

It was solved reinstalling Apache

```
yum reinstall httpd
```

Hope this help.
Rgds